# EDIT: What might be causing the weird differences the directory the python interpreter uses as home directory in similar installations?

Tags: python, windows, installation

I have a short script written in python that saves a simple .txt to the same directory the .py file is in. Problem is: It only does so on one of my two computers. 
My code doesn't include a hard-coded path to write to. On my laptop, I can put the makemeanote.py in any folder and it will create the note right there. On my desktop pc, all the notes end up in System32. PATH is set exactly the same way on both machines, and both use Windows\py.exe as the executable.

Somewhat interestingly, I only get an admin-screen on the desktop pc, asking if I want to allow changes to my system by "Built: Release_master_v3.8.2_"etc., whereas on my laptop it simply runs and does its job.

No amount of un- and reinstalling has changed anything, even when I thought I had eradicated any trace of python on my hard drive. Both PCs use current Win10/64 installations.

What is happening there?

A clarification: It's not about fixing the bug, it's about understanding the inconsistent behaviour! I know I could just hard-code any directory, but that takes away the beauty, don't you think?

Comment: The initial working directory of the python.exe process is either explicitly set by or implicitly inherited from its parent process. A script can change the working directory to match the script directory.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I was not so much looking for a fix per se but for a better understanding. I've just edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Normally when you run a file by double clicking on it in Explorer, it explicitly sets the working directory to the parent directory of the file. If you run a file from Win+R run dialog, it sets the working directory to the user profile directory. If you run a file from the shell, it inherits the shell's working directory. When elevating to administrator, the request to create an elevated process is sent to the appinfo service. Maybe this service API doesn't provide a way to set the working directory, so the elevated child simply inherits the parent's working directory, i.e. "System32".

Comment: Anyway, a script does not control the initial working directory and should make no assumption about it. If you need to create a file in the script directory, then reference it explicitly, such as `script_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`.

Comment: Thank you, Eryk! Yes, that was the double-clicking behavior I was expecting... But you're probably right about the service API.

Comment: Oh and thanks for the code, this will come in handy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the cause of the weird behavior:
For some reason, the py.exe in my WINDOWS folder was set to always be run as admin. As soon as I unchecked that option, the User Account Control (UAC) check disappeared and my file finally behaved as I had expected.